# BlocBuilder Error: Could not find the correct Provider<TransactionBloc>

Tags: flutter, macos, exception

The app shows me this exception whenever I try to select any page with relations to TransactionBloc.

Error: Could not find the correct `Provider<Transaction Bloc>` above this `BlocBuilder<TransactionBloc, List<Transaction>>` Widget. The below is my snippet of the code i'm currently using in my program:

```
body: BlocBuilder<TransactionBloc, List<Transaction>>(
          builder: (context, transactions) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: transactions.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final transaction = transactions[index];
                return Dismissible(
                  key: Key(transaction.id.toString()),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    context.read<TransactionBloc>().add(
                          DeleteTransactionEvent(transaction.id),
                        );
                  },
                  background: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  child: TransactionListItem(transaction: transaction),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            buildFloatingActionButton(
              context,
              Icons.refresh,
              () => context.read<TransactionBloc>().add(FetchTransactionsEvent())
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            buildFloatingActionButton(
              context,
              Icons.list,
              () => navigate(context, const TransactionsScreen()),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            buildFloatingActionButton(
              context,
              Icons.person,
              () => navigate(context, const ProfileScreen()),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
    buildFloatingActionButton(
      context,
      Icons.delete,
      () {
        // Replace 1 with the transactionId you want to delete
        context.read<TransactionBloc>().add(const DeleteTransactionEvent(1));
      },
    ),
```

So when this code runs, I should be able to see the Transaction History and also be able to delete a undo a transaction if it is set to auto payment.

Answer (score 0):

You should define state's class in second generic parameter, not `List` ->`body: BlocBuilder<TransactionBloc, TransactionState>`